# What is spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults for?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I found spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults property in the `application.yml` file and I can't find the docs related to this property's purpose.

What should this property be used for? Are there any official docs that describe it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the following description in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-internal):

> **hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults** (e.g. `true` (default value) or `false`)
>
> This setting is used to control whether we should consult the JDBC metadata to determine certain Settings default values when the database may not be available (mainly in tools usage).